# Location accuracy of Google Analytics for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-location

When testing Google Analytics (version 2) for an Android project, I noticed that the Real Time  map shows my location to be about 200 miles from my actual location. I'm running my project on a physical device, which leads me to believe that Google Analytics doesn't actually send any location information, but rather gets it from the phones IP address when the data is sent to Googles server. Is there any way to alter this behavior and provide my own location data using  getLastKnownLocation() for example? Sending it as an actual Label/Action string would of course work, but that means I can't use Google Analytics fancy map feature to view where my users are coming from.

Comment: Same problem here, I am in Stockholm, Sweden but Google Analytics thinks I am in Malmö, Sweden, 600 kms away. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Google Analytics uses the IP for determining the Location. The [support forum of Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144408?hl=en) accepts the fact that there can `City location may not be accurate for visits from mobile devices`

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize how Google gets the location data (which is by IP mapped location), however you can store custom dimensions and metrics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics isn't really intended for fine grain location tracking. A good and free platform for location tracking is Cintric https://cintric.com/ which will track very precise locations.

Its a drop in SDK like google analytics. You then get access to a dashboard with all your users locations a a bunch of analytics / visualizations. It supports both android and iOS.